# Countdown timer repeat?

Tags: swift, nstimer, scenekit

How can I make a countdown timer in that when it hits 0, my scene will run x actions? Then, how would I reset the timer back to repeat the whole process?

EX: timer starts at 5 seconds when scene loads. Timer counts down to 0 and  then an action will run within my scene. Upon completion of the action, timer resets back to 5.

Comment: Timer that triggers after 5 seconds is pretty straightforward; what's the hard part for you?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
let waitAction: SCNAction = SCNAction.wait(duration: 5.0)
let thisAction = SCNAction(some sort of action)
let sequenceAction = SCNAction.sequence([waitAction, thisAction])
let repeatAction = SCNAction.repeatForever(sequenceAction, duration: 5.0))

 theNode.runAction(repeatAction)
```

Comment: Using `SCNAction` is much more in tune with SceneKit's style than using a `Timer`.

Comment: @GregRobertson While I did think of this at first, once the timer hits zero one of four actions will occur; therefore, it cannot be in the node itself but the actual node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Timer** class to create the self-repeated timer with any next actions. As I understand, you use swift3.

Code is below:

```
Timer.init(timeInterval: 5.0, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
        print("Scene runned")
}).fire()
```

If you need more detailed info about the timer usage, look at the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer).